# Programmatically print .doc using a virtual printer

Tags: java

Is there a way to print a `.doc` file (this specific case) using a virtual printer without showing the print dialog?

I have tried using `javax.print` library and I can print(convert in this case) images and text files, using for example:

```
DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.JPEG;
PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
aset.add(MediaSizeName.ISO_A4);
aset.add(new Copies(1));
aset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED);

DocPrintJob pj = selectedPrinter.createPrintJob();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);
pj.print(doc, aset);
```

Trying following this logic with several other options with .doc files always result in a corrupted pdf.